# Complex concatenation on GROUP BY string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    title_imdb_id, person_imdb_id, role_type_id, role_name
FROM
    mturk_imdbcredit
WHERE
    title_imdb_id=1
```

Which gives me:

```
title_imdb_id   person_imdb_id  role_type_id    role_name
1   1588970 Actor   Herself
1   5690    Director    NULL
```

I would like to group by the `title_imdb_id` and concatenate the three fields separated by a `:` and the rows separated by a `,`. The end result should be:

```
1588970:Actor:Herself, 5690:Director:
```

Is this possible to do in `SQL` ?

Comment: Are there always exactly 1 Actor and 1 Director? in other words, do you want exactly 2 columns, or can there be any number (eg for lots of actors for a given title)

Comment: There can be lots of credits

Comment: @Bohemian see answer below. It can be done with a group_concat.

Comment: yes - I misunderstood the question; I thought you wanted each actor/director *in a separate column* (not in the one column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a field concat in addition to a [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/):

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT (
          person_imdb_id, ':', role_type_id, ':', IFNULL(role_name, '')
        ) SEPARATOR ', '
    )
FROM
    mturk_imdbcredit
GROUP BY
    title_imdb_id
```

Which gives me:

```
1588970:Actor:Herself, 5690:Director:
```